# Prove if $f(A)=g(A)$, $f(B)=g(B)$, and $f(C)=g(C)$, then $f=g$.

Tags: isometry

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are isometries and $A, B, C$ are non-collinear. Prove that if
$f(A) = g(A)$, $f(B) = g(B)$, and $f(C) = g(C)$ then $f = g$.

I was thinking that because every isometry has an inverse which is also an isometry, then $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$, and we know that $g(f^{-1}(f(A)))=f(A)=g(A)$, so then the function $g(f^{-1})$ has three fixed points, namely $f(A)$, $f(B)$, and $f(C)$, then $g(f^{-1}) = i$ (identity transformation)  So then the inverse of $g$ is $f^{-1}$, so $g=f$.

Is this a solution to the problem or did I do something incorrect?

Comment: You haven't used non-collinearity.

Comment: You're right.  If $f$ is an isometry and $A,B,C$ are non-collinear, then will $f(A),f(B),f(C)$ also be non-collinear?

Comment: Actually, I was going to point out that the result isn't true if $A,B,C$ *are* collinear. So you have to use non-collinearity somewhere in your proof.